# MVC page loading with images loads to bottom

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with C# and MVC.  I have implemented lazy loading using the [Vanilla Lazyloading](http://verlok.github.io/lazyload/) routine.  It works well.

The problem I have is different behavior with how the page behaves in MVC vs. the same page in a HTML file.  When it is part of the MVC app, it page loads down to the bottom in Chrome and IE, and just past the first row of photos in Firefox .  When I take the generated source code and put it in an HTML file, it stays at the top, regardless of browser.

MVC View (ignore the model, since I have commented out my code and have hardcoded the photo loading for this purpose)

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.PictureMin>

<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/1_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/2_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/3_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/4_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/5_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/6_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/7_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/8_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">

<script src="~/Scripts/lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
        threshold: 50
    });
</script>
```

This view generates with following HTML code, which if I save and run separately (and adjusting the paths to load the images and javascript), loads like it should, staying at the top of the page instead of at the bottom:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> - My App</title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-green.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="Content/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> Database</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Item1">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Item2">Item 2 List</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Photo">Photographs</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Item 4">Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">



<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/1_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/2_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/3_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/4_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/5_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/6_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/7_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="Content/Images/photos/8_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<script src="Scripts/lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
        threshold: 50,
    });
</script>

    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2017 </p>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/lightbox.min.js"></script>




<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"e15b189278d8494e962f117ad56c415f"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:51950/66a9aeb429bb43b9951e62c2ce437bf0/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what is making the MVC app page to the bottom and how to correct it?

Comment: If you have web essentials extension, you might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42651346/4305494

Comment: That was it!  In VS 2015, I turned it off and the problem went away.  Also, I just installed VS 2017, with browser link enabled, and the problem doesn't exist.  What is the proper way to close this out with the comments?  Also, I am surprised I didn't find the link you gave, Ricky, since I always search before I post.

Comment: don't worry I also struggled to find anything related to the problem. I will flag your questions as a duplicate, when I get to the office, and eventually people will vote to close it. Cheers.

Comment: I also included an answer in that question that does not involve changing Web.config if that suits you better.

Comment: This isn't an incredibly complex mvc app, and I am a solo developer, so switching to VS 2017 is fairly easy.  The problem went away with at least Chrome and FF.  I will take your advice if somehow I need to switch back to VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Layout` file has a call to `RenderBody` which renders the content of your `View` file in that space, your View file does not indicate to the Layout that your `<script>` code should be loaded *after* other scripts: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor

This is what "sections" are used for in Razor layout files (in WebForms these were known as `<asp:ContentPlaceholder />` elements).

In your Layout, specify a location for the separate content using `@RenderSection()` and in your `View` specify the content for the section with `@section {}`.

...like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.PictureMin>

<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/1_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
<img data-original="/Content/Images/photos/2_thumbnail.jpg" width="400" height="400">
...

@section Scripts {

<script src="~/Scripts/lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
        threshold: 50
    });
</script>

}
```

And in your Layout:

```
...

@RenderBody()

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/lightbox.min.js"></script>

@RenderSection("Scripts")

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I learned something and added what you suggested to both the layout and the view.   Semi-unfortunately, it didn't make a difference.  I say "semi" because when I uploaded it to IIS, the page rendered properly, so it must be something odd about the local webserver vs IIS.